# Drake: Why are there multiple geometryId for the same link in a MultibodyPlant?

Tags: drake

I have 6 real links (named left distal, left proximal, right distal, right proximal, palm, and ball) + 2 dummy links (so the ball can move freely in x-y plane) in my URDFs. I want to know which geometryId corresponds to which link so I can check for contact. However, there are far more geometryId registered than links in the system. So I try to print out the body names through the geometryIds and found multiple geometryIds with the same body name. Then from Drake's render_multibody_plant.ipynb tutorial I saw this line `geometry_label = inspector.GetPerceptionProperties(geometry_id).GetProperty("label", "id")` so I printed the same for my geometryIds. However, some of them returns `None`. When I print out `int(geometry_label)` for those that are not `None`, I get exactly 6 numbers (but multiple of the same number for some of the links!). 
I don't understand what those extra geometry_ids are for and how to find the geometryIds that I actually care for.

Here is relevant code:

```
builder = DiagramBuilder()
# plant, scene_graph = AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(builder, time_step=0.00001)
plant, scene_graph = AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(builder, time_step=0.)
file_name = FindResource("models/myhand.urdf")
gripper_model = Parser(plant).AddModelFromFile(file_name)
file_name = FindResource("models/sphere.urdf")
object_model = Parser(plant).AddModelFromFile(file_name)
scene_graph_context = scene_graph.AllocateContext()
plant.Finalize()
plant.set_name('hand')


controller = ConstantVectorSource([-7, 7])
torque_system = builder.AddSystem(controller)
builder.Connect(torque_system.get_output_port(0), plant.get_actuation_input_port())

# Setup visualization
T_xy = np.array([[ 1., 0., 0., 0.], [ 0., 1., 0., 0.], [ 0., 0., 0., 1.]])
T_xz = np.array([[ 1., 0., 0., 0.], [ 0., 0., 1., 0.], [ 0., 0., 0., 1.]])
visualizer = builder.AddSystem(
    PlanarSceneGraphVisualizer(scene_graph, T_VW=T_xy, xlim=[-0.3, 0.3], ylim=[-0.3, 0.3], show=plt_is_interactive))

builder.Connect(scene_graph.get_pose_bundle_output_port(),
                visualizer.get_input_port(0))


diagram = builder.Build()

diagram_context = diagram.CreateDefaultContext()
scene_graph_context = scene_graph.GetMyContextFromRoot(diagram_context) 
plant_context = plant.GetMyContextFromRoot(diagram_context) 

# Set up a simulator to run this diagram
simulator = Simulator(diagram)
context = simulator.get_mutable_context()

# simulate from zero to duration
simulator.Initialize()


# Simulate
duration = 0.5 if get_ipython() else 0.1 # sets a shorter duration during testing
context.SetTime(0.0)

AdvanceToAndVisualize(simulator, visualizer, duration)

query_object = scene_graph.get_query_output_port().Eval(scene_graph_context)
inspector = query_object.inspector()


for geometry_id in inspector.GetAllGeometryIds():
    body = plant.GetBodyFromFrameId(inspector.GetFrameId(geometry_id))
    print(body.name())

    geometry_label = inspector.GetPerceptionProperties(
        geometry_id)
    if geometry_label != None:
        print(int(geometry_label.GetProperty("label", "id")))
```

Here's output to the print statement:

```
ball
ball
6
right_distal
right_distal
5
right_distal
5
left_distal
left_distal
4
left_distal
4
right_proximal
right_proximal
3
right_proximal
3
left_proximal
left_proximal
2
left_proximal
2
palm
palm
1
```

Note: running PyDrake on a Jupyter Notebook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifically, each link can register collision and visual geometry. Even if the two geometries specify shapes with identical parameters, those shapes are not consolidated to a single geometry. So, you'll get one GeometryId for each collision and visual geometry associated with a link.

Those declared as visual in your URDF will have non-None `PerceptionProperties` (and `IllutrationProperties`). But their `ProximityProperties` will be None. Conversely, those declared as collision geometries will have non-`None` `ProximityProperties` but `None` for the other two types.

Answer (score 2):

I would expect to have a separate geometry ID for each visual element in your body (not one per body).  Does your URDF have multiple visual elements in each body?

The "Body frames and SceneGraph frames" [documentation for MultibodyPlant](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_multibody_plant.html) appears to have the answer you're looking for:

> Given a GeometryId, SceneGraph cannot report what body it is affixed to. It can only report the SceneGraph alias frame F. But the following idiom can report the body:

```
const MultibodyPlant<T>& plant = ...;
const SceneGraphInspector<T>& inspector =  ...;
const GeometryId g_id = id_from_some_query;
const FrameId f_id = inspector.GetFrameId(g_id);
const Body<T>* body = plant.GetBodyFromFrameId(f_id);
```

> See documentation of geometry::SceneGraphInspector on where to get an inspector.

Comment: Although for some links I have multiple visual elements, the ball only has one visual element and still has two geometryIds linked to it. The linked body name is printed from `plant.GetBodyFromFrameId(inspector.GetFrameId(geometry_id)).name()` as in the code at the very bottom.

Comment: Although the documentation say that the geometryIds from `.GetAllGeometryIds()` is not in any particular order, at least it's been very consistent for me and I was able to index into the list of geometryIds to get the ones I need, although not for best practice..